# Add field to JavaScript object, which counts number of corresponding objects by their id

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object with 2 arrays, each array containing some objects, like so:

```
var obj = {
    'parent' : [

        { id : 'ID_A', name : 'Joe'  }
        , { id : 'ID_B', name : 'Jim'  }
        , { id : 'ID_C', name : 'Edward'  }
        , { id : 'ID_D', name : 'Gary'  }
    ],

    'child' : [

        { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_B' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_B' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_C' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_D' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_D' }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add a new field to each `parent` object and call it `child_count`. This field would be the number of `child` objects that contain a `parent_id` field whose value matches the `id` field of each object in the `parent` array.

So the finished product would look like this:

```
var obj = {
    'parent' : [

        { id : 'ID_A', name : 'Joe', child_count : 3  }
        , { id : 'ID_B', name : 'Jim', child_count : 2  }
        , { id : 'ID_C', name : 'Edward', child_count : 3  }
        , { id : 'ID_D', name : 'Gary', child_count : 0  }
    ],

    'child' : [

        { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_A' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_B' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_B' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_C' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_C' }
        , { id : 'SOME_ID', parent_id : 'ID_C' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @thatOneGuy nothing that's produced any decent results. I'm using the underscore library, I feel I should have cracked it already but I think I've hit a wall.

Comment: no need for a library for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over every parent. For every parent, filter out children with his ID. Getting the length of the filtered child array gives you the number of children per parent.

Some info about the `filter` method: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
obj.parent.forEach(function(parent) {
    parent.child_count = obj.child.filter(function(child) {
    return child.parent_id === parent.id;
  }).length;
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/exooyLo9/1/

Comment: Nice implementation, way better than mine ++

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for reference to the parent object and iterate the for the count.

```js
var obj = { 'parent': [{ id: 'ID_A', name: 'Joe' }, { id: 'ID_B', name: 'Jim' }, { id: 'ID_C', name: 'Edward' }, { id: 'ID_D', name: 'Gary' }], 'child': [{ id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_A' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_A' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_A' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_B' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_B' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_C' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_D' }, { id: 'SOME_ID', parent_id: 'ID_D' }] },
    pointer = Object.create(null);

obj.parent.forEach(function (a) {
    a.child_count = 0;
    pointer[a.id] = a;
});

obj.child.forEach(function (a) {
    pointer[a.parent_id].child_count++;

});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: but your solution has a greater complexity.

Comment: Disagree, @Pimmol is really easy to understand

Comment: **O(n+m)** vs **O(n*m)**. it has nothing to do with easy to understand, but with complexity. filter iterates over all elements and just for count, its the wrong method.

Comment: the first loops over `parent`, the second over `child` -- once.

Comment: Ok I understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

Example fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/5113jumw/1/

Just create an attribute childCount and set it to 0 :

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.parent.length; i++) {
  obj.parent[i].childCount = 0;
}
```

Then loop through children and check their parent. When found increment parent child count by 1 :

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.child.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < obj.parent.length; j++) {

    if (obj.child[i].parent_id == obj.parent[j].id) {
      obj.parent[j].childCount++;
    }

  }
}
```